# Convert Unicode Integer into Unicode Character in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do you convert a Unicode Integer into a Unicode Character in SQL Server 2005.

For example, SELECT UNICODE('$') returns 36.

I am looking for a function that takes 36 and returns '$'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NChar should convert back, takes a range of 0 through 65535

```
Select NChar(36)

Returns '$'
```